# Pull Django App from Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have built a web app using Django and I'm using Heroku to host it. There is a form where users can enter information and that information is stored in a database (db.SQLITE3). So everything is getting stored in the database which is on the server. Next time when I'm pushing my project after making some changes, the updated server database is getting replaced by my backdated local database which basically deletes the new information. So, I realized, I have to pull (Obviously) the server side code first before making the changes.

I have tried

    `heroku db:pull`

which gives an error

    `db:pull is not a heroku command.
    !    Perhaps you meant pg:pull?`

So I tried

    `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL db --app mywebapp`
 
which is giving an error

    `heroku-cli: Pulling postgresql-reticulated-26036 ---> db
    'createdb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`

I'm really confused now, can someone please tell me how to pull the project from Heroku? Or maybe how I can get the updated database?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use sqlite on Heroku. You *must* use the Postgres add-on.

Comment: Also note SQLite3 is serverless, read about its advatanges and disadvantages! [Source](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html)